# Arithmetic Sequences Problem 54

Tags: arithmetic

What is the sum of all integers between 1 and 6000 which are aren't divisible by 5 or 4?

The only method I could think of is finding all the multiples of 4 and 5 between 1 and 6000 and adding them together. Then finding the sum of all the numbers from 1 to 6000 and subtracting the other sum from this sum to find the answer. But this method isn't at all efficient so can you please help me in finding a method that is efficient?

Comment: Do you know how to use a conditional loop in a computer program?  I would simple create a list 1 to 6000, go through it and ask the number was divisible by 4 or 5.  Then sum this list.  Python would be easy.

Comment: $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$

Comment: what would the code for the python thing be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum all the numbers from $1$ to $6000$. The sum of all the multiples of $4$ is four times the sum of all the numbers from $1$ to $1500$.  Subtract that.  Subtract the sum of all the multiples of $5$.  Now the multiples of $20$ ....  This is called the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: would the sum of the numbers that aren't divisible by 5 and 4 between 1 and 6000 be 10800000?

Comment: That is what I get.